# One way drag and drop elements between lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, html-lists

I use this library - http://dragsort.codeplex.com/ for reordering DOM lists. It is pretty lightweight and does what it's supposed to. It also has a 'dragbetween' option to drag between lists. It does not support one way dragging and dropping however. Is there any library that supports dragging and dropping between lists, but only one way?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : To avoid confusion - I want to move elements from List A to B but not from B to A

Comment: Yeah that is the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jquery's sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/),

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divA").sortable({
        connectWith: '#divB',
        delay: 250
    });
});
```

This would let you drag between A to B only, not from B to A.

To make it draggable between both,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#divA").sortable({
            connectWith: '#divB',
            delay: 250
        });
        $("#divB").sortable({
            connectWith: '#divA',
            delay: 250
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know if there's a lighter lib ?

Comment: @cowboybebop not one that i am aware of, but jquery's ui has many other features too with which you can make your applications very interactive. I would suggest you to include this in your project. You mat though search for jquery ui min version.

Comment: yes sir, yes it was. The reason I didn't go for jquery ui initially was the bulkiness. I tried to reduce my js footprint as much as possible. I found this too (http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) and will check it out, but thanks a million, commander of the autobots.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery UI sortable.

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

You only need to specify one list with the "connectWith" option, that's it.